# How to identify ARMA order of Panel Regression

Tags: time-series, arima, panel-data, model-selection, box-jenkins

I am familiar with methods to determine the Autoregressive and Move Average orders of ARIMAX type models in a univariate time-series context, usually formulated as regression with ARMA errors. I am particularly partial to the Box-Jenkins method of identifying an appropriate ARMA order as I find it typically leads to more parsimonious orders compared to AIC/SBC based methods.

Now suppose I have an unbalanced panel dataset with a collection of hundreds of related time-series. Most time-series have 200+ observations while others have as few as ~40. Are there any methods similar to the Box-Jenkins method for identifying the ARMA orders for panel regression?

At first glance, it seems to me that the ACF and PACF only apply to a univariate time-series. Would an average of each individual ACF and PACF be an appropriate diagnosis method?